# apache blocking content from viewing users by hitting url directly

Tags: apache, tomcat, server

I have disabled the browsing of content by using

> Options -Indexes

Now I want to disable directly access of assets(images and videos) by hitting url directly for any project that is present in htdocs folder.

1. My webserver is Apache Tomcat.
2. I am accessing the content from a project in apache using a url.
3. The URL should serve the content in JSP/HTML files deployed in Apache Tomcat. But should be blocked if hacker finds the URL from page source and put the URL in browser.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you tell me where should it located in windows xampp setup

Comment: You should create a .htaccess file in *every* directory you want to protect. The files should contain a single line: `Deny from all`.

Comment: Please see my edits in question. This will not resolve my problem.

Comment: Good to know you are using Tomcat. Just writing "Apache" implies HTTPD, for which the .htaccess approach works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two solutions

1) create a .htacess file and set rules

2) store your protected file somewhere outside the web root folder and acess them using php or any other language.

2nd one is recommended. you can only access your files through server side codes(php,...). Crete a file handling script and check permissions when accessing.

To go with .htaccess file you need to have something like..

Try following:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg)$ - [F]
```

Returns 403 if you access image directly, but allows them to be displayed on site.

Change localhost to the server/domain name of yours.

NOTE: it is possible that when you open some page with image and than copy that image's path into the address bar you can see that image, it is only because of the browser's cache, in fact that image has not been loaded from the server

Comment: Thanks. Let me check the methods.

Comment: could you please tell me how to create .htacess file and where should I place it on windows xampp apache server.

Comment: could you help me in creating .htacess file, please suggest me to how to write the access and blocking statements in the file.

Comment: Could you please tell me if the content(which is hidden using .htaccess) I can use in my project.

Comment: yes it will allow the files to be accessed by the site. It will only allow the requests initiated by the same server (localhost).

Comment: And also u can mark this as the answer if it is.. :D

Comment: ok. Thank you very much. But I am using Apache Tomcat as a web server that is different. so is there any solution for this problem... Anyway I'll mark this as a answer.

Comment: it is not allowing the files to be accessed by the site.

Comment: change localhost to your domain. (u can find it in ur url)

Comment: This haven't resolved my problem.. Anyway I'll ask an another question.

Comment: I'll mark this as answer if no body gives the answer. Please see the edits in question.